# How can I redirect a user to a new page in IIS based upon the URL

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a web app that opens certain projects based upon a projectID

So ID 12345 = project **foobar**

http://my.example.com?projID=12345

However I would like to provide a different site that doesnt require the projectid, and is easier to remember for the end user.

So if a user visits

http://simple.example.com/foobar (note this is a different site, though I suppose we could put this in the same site if easier)

They would automatically get redirected to

http://my.example.com?projID=12345

Obviously I would want a system where I could have more entries than just foobar

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the rewrite module mentioned above you could always do it yourself by implementing a custom 404 handler and key off aspxerrorpath or perhaps putting the code in a custom httpHandler.

We actually do this with in one of our applications.  We use a cms system to specify all of the redirects so nothing is really hard coded and marketers and SEO teams can handle it without our help.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should use `ashx` to handle web request. here is very simple and beautiful example of what you are looking for :-

http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx